# Recuperar apenas bairro e cidade na API do Google Maps pelas coordenadas em PHP puro

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocalização, maps-javascript-api

Tenho uma aplicação em que preciso guardar no banco de dados mysql apenas os dados de bairro e cidade, dos resultados vindos em json da api do Google Maps.
Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
 $url ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . $latitude . ',' . $longitude . '&key=';
 $geocode = file_get_contents($url);
 $results = json_decode($geocode, true);
 if($results['status']=='OK'){
$location = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'];
$location2 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name'];
```

}

O problema neste sistema, é que o resultado json não é padronizado, ou seja, em alguns momentos o bairro vem na posição 2 de address_components, em outros na posição 1, em outros na posição 0...
Preciso de orientação sobre como fazer, em PHP puro, sem javascript, para obter sempre o bairro e a cidade.
A estrutura json da requisição padrão está abaixo, porém em address_componentes nem sempre segue esta ordem:

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "plus_code": {
            "compound_code": "CWC8+W5 Mountain View, California, United States",
            "global_code": "849VCWC8+W5"
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Agradeço muito a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver aqui. Segue abaixo o script:

```
 $url ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . $latitude . ',' . $longitude . '&key=SuaKeyApiGoogleMaps';
 $geocode = file_get_contents($url);
 $results = json_decode($geocode, true);
 if($results['status']=='OK'){

    $location = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'];
    $location2 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'];
    $location3 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'];
    $location4 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name'];
    $location5 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][4]['long_name'];
    $type = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['types'];
    $type2 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['types'];
    $type3 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['types'];
    $type4 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['types'];
    $type5 = $results['results'][0]['address_components'][4]['types'];
 }
 if (in_array('sublocality_level_1', $type)) {
     $bairro = $location;
 }
 if (in_array('sublocality_level_1', $type2)) {
     $bairro = $location2;
 }
 if (in_array('sublocality_level_1', $type3)) {
     $bairro = $location3;
 }
 if (in_array('sublocality_level_1', $type4)) {
     $bairro = $location4;
 }
 if (in_array('sublocality_level_1', $type5)) {
     $bairro = $location5;
 }

 if (in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $type)) {
     $cidade = $location;
 }
 if (in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $type2)) {
     $cidade = $location2;
 }
 if (in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $type3)) {
     $cidade = $location3;
 }
 if (in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $type4)) {
     $cidade = $location4;
 }
 if (in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $type5)) {
     $cidade = $location5;
 }
```